# Proving that the Normalised Log Likelihood is not complete

Tags: statistics, log-likelihood

Setting:
N iid normalised random variables ~ N(μ, 1).
The normalised log -likelihood is a function-valued statistic. It is:
$S(X)= \cfrac{N \mu^2}{2}+ \mu \sum_{i=1}^{N}{Xi} $.
It is easy to prove that S is minimally sufficient for $\mu$ but I don't see how to prove it is not complete.
I tried to find some functional of S whose expectation would depend uniquely on the known variance...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If $\mu$ is unknown, how is your $S(X)$ a statistic of the observations?